# Write contents of all xml files into text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Folder LogBackup contains 40K xml files.
I want to read each xml file and copy its contents on different line of text file.
For example, if I have 2 xml files:

xmlFile1.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1" ?><Acknowledgement><HeaderData><Description>Estimate</Description> <SiteQueueName>QUEUE</SiteQueueName><LineItems>7</LineItems><TimeStamp>201408310925444111</TimeStamp></HeaderData><OrderDetail>
```

xmlFile2.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1" ?><Acknowledgement><HeaderData><Description>Estimate</Description> <SiteQueueName>QUEUE2</SiteQueueName><LineItems>7</LineItems><TimeStamp>201408310925380810</TimeStamp></HeaderData><OrderDetail>
```

Both of these should be copied to output.log:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1" ?><Acknowledgement><HeaderData><Description>Estimate</Description> <SiteQueueName>QUEUE</SiteQueueName><LineItems>7</LineItems><TimeStamp>201408310925444111</TimeStamp></HeaderData><OrderDetail>
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1" ?><Acknowledgement><HeaderData><Description>Estimate</Description> <SiteQueueName>QUEUE2</SiteQueueName><LineItems>7</LineItems><TimeStamp>201408310925380810</TimeStamp></HeaderData><OrderDetail>
```

This is what I got so far, but it is not working :(

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\LogBackup" -Filter *.xml | 
Foreach-Object 
{
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
    #save content to a new file 
    $content | Set-Content ('output.log')
}
```

Comment: Try using LogParser https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx

Comment: @RonHarlev I forgot to mention that nothing can be installed on the machine. I can't even get Notepad++ on it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set-Content
```

Replaces the existing data in a file.

```
Add-Content
```

Appends data to a file.

Therefore, you are only writing the last XML you check to the output.log file, and the rest is discarded along the way.

Here's the [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176959.aspx) article, for reference.

... and the modified code snippet (note I dump the output.log at the top, now):

```
Clear-Content ('C:\LogBackup\Output.log')
Get-ChildItem "C:\LogBackup" -Filter *.xml |
Foreach-Object 
{
   $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
   $content | Add-Content ('C:\LogBackup\Output.log')
}
```

Yielded:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1" ?><Acknowledgement><HeaderData><Description>Estimate</Description> <SiteQueueName>QUEUE</SiteQueueName><LineItems>7</LineItems><TimeStamp>201408310925444111</TimeStamp></HeaderData><OrderDetail>
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1" ?><Acknowledgement><HeaderData><Description>Estimate</Description> <SiteQueueName>QUEUE2</SiteQueueName><LineItems>7</LineItems><TimeStamp>201408310925380810</TimeStamp></HeaderData><OrderDetail>
```